# Allow moderators to edit the edit summary after an edit has exited the grace period

Tags: feature-request, edits, moderator-tools, edit-summary

Very occasionally, users leave edit summaries which are downright inappropriate. At present, the best we can do in such instances is to contact a Stack Exchange employee and ask for a revision purge, which is a very invasive operation.

Diamond moderators are entrusted with the ability to edit almost anything on their sites, including other peoples' comments also after the normal five minute grace period. (This is something not even the poster of the comment can do.)

I am proposing that diamond moderators **be given the ability to somehow edit the edit summary of a post revision after the fact,** in such a way that the originally entered edit summary is visible to other moderators and possibly high-rep users (but not others) in much the same way as deleted posts are visible to moderators and high-rep users only.